# Designing a Good Hash Function for Set Length URL Shortening in PHP

Tags: php, url, string, hash

I'm working on a URL shortener. The input is a URL and the output needs to be a 4 character string (alphanumeric, case-sensitive).

I calculated it out that if I use 4 characters with a case-sensitive alphanumeric key space I should potentially be able to store 64^4 (16777216) URLs until I run out of space.

I also don't want my URL shortener to generate any short URLs that are offensive four letter words. It would be unfortunate if someone made a short URL that was domain.com/f**k. You get the picture...

Any ideas on the best way to go about this? I feel like I'll be using base64_encode somewhere in the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I would make a case sensitive alphanumeric increment-er.  Just increment, and assign the number to a database row.  To check for bad words, just check against a black list.  If it passes, great.  If not, just increment again.

This way, instead of a hash algorithm, they're just in order.  The first few would look like this:

```
id   | url
-------------------------
0000 | http://google.com
0001 | http://yahoo.com
0002 | http://example.com
...
000a | http://mail.google.com
000b | http://adobe.com
...
000A | http://microsof.com
...
0010 | http://w3.org
...
00a0 | http://youtube.com
...
00A0 | http://stackoverflow.com
```

And so on.

Here's a hint on how the function will work:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php

BTW, my math might be wrong, but I think it's (10 + 26 + 26) ^ 4 = 14776336

**Edit**: Just for the fun and the challenge, I wrote an incrementer function.  When the max is reached, it returns false, so just compare it to false (with ===) when using it.

http://pastebin.com/957KPn4p

Comment: Hey Jonah - this is so awesome! Thank you so much for your excellent response.

Comment: Any thoughts on a function that will receive one of these values and kick out the integer it represents? =]

Comment: I could think about it,... why?  If you're thinking about the database index, you can use the number as it is.

Answer (score 1):

It vaguely reminded me of this[How do I create unique IDs, like YouTube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076110/how-do-i-create-unique-ids-like-youtube). You just have to be sure to check (in a more limited space) the possibility of a collision.