# Return case-sensitive files on apache php linux host

Tags: php, linux, apache, case-sensitive

I'm using a free hosting (linux[apache,php,mysql]) to test some php scripts ..

one of them is using and algorythm to create an unique identifier (UID) from a mysql id.

so `1` becomes `aaaaaaaab` and so on.

I'm using that UID string to store the images on the server (works).

Now i just found out that the filesystem in reading is caseinsensitive.

So i have `aaaaaaaab.jpg` & `aaaaaaaaB.jpg` but i always get only the uppercase image first.

---

**Is there a way to return the correct image with php?**

---

**Note1:** i'm able to store the images with both uppercase and lowercase.(Normal, linux filesystem is case sensitive)

**Note2:** As this is a free hosting i probably can't use .htaccess or modify the php,filesystem settings. But i also accept answers that include .htaccess solutions if Note3 is incorrect.

**Note3:** They have a ticket system but don't answer.

**Note4:** Everything works on my local server.

---

**What i tried:**

directlink - 'ht*p://myurl.test/img/aaaaaaaab.jpg'

`file_get_contents('aaaaaaaab.jpg')`

`fopen('aaaaaaaab.jpg',r)`

also a redirect script on 404 'ht*p://myurl.test/aaaaaaaab'

in all this cases i get the 'aaaaaaaaB.jpg'

---

*I also read most of the already answered questions here.but they mostly consist of modifying the filesystem or the php settings & (htaccess, but not in the correct way for my case)*

---

**the filesystem is case-sensitive (write) & case-insensitive (read)**

---

UID script..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18455796/2450730

Comment: Just use strtolower()?

Comment: i have both files on the server, so aaaaaaaB.jpg & aaaaaaab.jpg. but i always get only aaaaaaaB.jpg

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestions would be to move to a different hoster. A filesystem is either case sensitive or case insenstive for read and write. Everything else makes absolutely no sense. (And the hoster is not responding to support tickets - but what do you expect for nothing.)

If that is not possible, you could remove the upper-case letters from the UID-script or generate a unique id in another way without using both upper- and lower-case values.

Comment: 'but what do you expect for nothing' ..it's a very good host except they don't answer and the filesystem is a mess :(. i thought the same but finding another host like that isn't easy.Also messing up the UID script would have a very high impact to the number of UID's i could create.anyway considering your answer as a solution if i don't get more.thx

Answer (score 0):

I would rename the files.

Change your algorithm to use only one case and rename all your existing files (I assume you want to keep what you've stored). Remember when you rename a file it will always rename the uppercase one first, so you'd move all your files with uppercase names to a new name.

Comment: renaming wouldn't be a big problem.. i have the exact same copy on local server.i just wanted to test the UID script :) in this case.. thats why i'm trying so hard to find a 'test' solution to output the correct file.

Answer (score 0):

Mod_alias on the host may be configured to do case insensitive matches, so you could remove that.

However, this scheme in general seems like a terrible idea. If you have an ID, you can just use that. Or create an actual UUID or use uniqid().

Comment: do you have an example how to configure the mod_alias with php?